# convert jquery dynamic ajax div function to vue.js

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, vue.js

I have the following:

html:

```
<div data-ajaxdiv="sidebar__blog"></div> 
<div data-ajaxdiv="content__blog_posts"></div>
```

etc...

jquery:

```
window.onload = gatherajaxdivs;

function ajaxdiv(element){  
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            action: 'ajaxdiv',
            subaction: element.attr('data-ajaxdiv')
        },
        success: function (data) {
            element.html(data);
        }
    });
}

function gatherajaxdivs(){
    $('[data-ajaxdiv]').each(function(){
        ajaxdiv($(this));
    }); 
}
```

The ajax data returns dynamic html code from my database to the elements. It's working great, but learning vue now, and step by step I'm converting my old jquery to new vue code.

I've searched hours on the internet for tutorials/blogs how to build this simple function in vue, but I can't find what i'm looking for. Can someone get me started with a simple example?

Answer (score 0):

Vue does not come with AJAX functionality. You can perform AJAX calls using the built in JavaScript XMLHttpRequest Object:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Or you can use a library which has an easier API and built in promises like Axios:

https://github.com/axios/axios

This free tutorial might help you out with Axios:

https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/18

Comment: I would also recommend VueResource (https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource) which is super easy to setup and use.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into axios, heard of that. The biggest problem is "selecting" the div elements with the data-ajax attribute.